# Why is this DTD not valid?

Tags: xml, attributes, element, dtd

I've tried validating this DTD using 1-2 validators, however I'm unsure on why it is not valid:

DTD code:

Any help will be appreciated!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE cars 
[
    <!ELEMENT car (maker, model, year, colour, engine, number_of_doors, accessories)>

    <!ELEMENT maker (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT model (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT year (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT colour (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT engine (number_of_cylinders)>
    <!ELEMENT number_of_doors (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT accessories (#PCDATA)>

    <!ELEMENT number_of_cylinders (#PCDATA)>

    <!ATTLIST accessories radio (yes|no) #REQUIRED
        air_conditioning (yes|no) #REQUIRED
        power_windows (yes|no) #REQUIRED
        power_steering (yes|no) #REQUIRED
        power_brakes (yes|no) #REQUIRED
    >
]>
```

Comment: Show your input XML and tell us what error messages the validators gave.

Answer (score 0):

To make your XML document with an internal DTD subset be valid, make the following changes:

1. Change the document element from `cars` to `car`.
2. Build out the XML associated with the given internal subset.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE car 
   [
   <!ELEMENT car (maker, model, year, colour, engine, number_of_doors, accessories)>

   <!ELEMENT maker (#PCDATA)>
   <!ELEMENT model (#PCDATA)>
   <!ELEMENT year (#PCDATA)>
   <!ELEMENT colour (#PCDATA)>
   <!ELEMENT engine (number_of_cylinders)>
   <!ELEMENT number_of_doors (#PCDATA)>
   <!ELEMENT accessories (#PCDATA)>

   <!ELEMENT number_of_cylinders (#PCDATA)>

   <!ATTLIST accessories radio (yes|no) #REQUIRED
       air_conditioning (yes|no) #REQUIRED
       power_windows (yes|no) #REQUIRED
       power_steering (yes|no) #REQUIRED
       power_brakes (yes|no) #REQUIRED>
   ]>
   <car>
       <!-- Finish building out the XML per the internal subset. -->
   </car>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this validator is the best for DTD https://validator.w3.org/check